# Extracting lines for a range in a column with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a huge `gzipped` file, which I want to extract certain lines of it, according to a range in its second column.

The start of a `file1.txt.gz` is:

```
zcat file1.txt.gz | head
1 1001 F K 999
1 1002 N G 340
1 1003 H B 889
1 1004 D F 399
1 1005 C X 311
2 1002 E F 233
2 1002 F C 334
3 1001 F C 331
```

I want to extract the lines starting with `1` and, having their `second columns` from `1001` to `1003` (including `1003`).

So the expected output is:

```
1 1001 F K 999
1 1002 N G 340
1 1003 H B 889
```

I am `unzipping` the head of the zipped file, then applying the following command, it works, gives the expected output. ( `zcat file1.txt.gz | head | LC_ALL=C parallel -j 32 --block 10M --pipe grep -w "^1" | awk '$2 ~ /'1001'/,/'1003'/'` )

However, if I start with `unzipping`, the `awk` range filtering does not work, and it grabs everything starting with `1`:

```
zcat file1.txt.gz | LC_ALL=C parallel -j 32 --block 10M --pipe grep -w "^1" | awk '$2 ~ /'1001'/,/'1003'/'  > output.txt
```

Right now, the `output.txt`:

```
1 1001 F K 999
1 1002 N G 340
1 1003 H B 889
1 1004 D F 399
1 1005 C X 311
```

PS: I am calling the command from a `bash` script, and accepting the ranges  ( `1001` and `1003` ) from user input.

Can you tell me what I am missing and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With column `1` starting with `1` as you stated in your POST :

```
zcat file1.txt.gz | awk '/^1/ && $2 >= 1001 && $2 <= 1003'
```

or if you need column 1 to be `1` literal:

```
zcat file1.txt.gz | awk '$1 == 1 && $2 >= 1001 && $2 <= 1003'
```

### Output :

```
1 1001 F K 999
1 1002 N G 340
1 1003 H B 889
```

### A bit of explanation :

- there's no `{print}` statement here, because the default behavior of [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) is to *print* when a `TRUE` condition is met

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However,would it be fast enough?  The zipped file is 400GB, and using `parallel` was making it much faster

Comment: @bapors, please give codes once try and let us know how it goes then.

Comment: If you have tried something, in any case add it to your post, it's how SO works (SO rules)

Comment: Moreover, I dunno what you expect to run N process in // and have one result and awk is fast by nature. I doubt you can found something faster, but if you can explain us, we will be happy to learn something new

Comment: rearranging conditions may make it faster  `'$1 == 1 && $2 <= 1003 && $2 >= 1001'`

Comment: Sure, it's a literal match, not a regex. We just try to understand what you mean by _starting with 1_, not _that_ clear

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you. This will look for first column should be `1`.

```
zcat file1.txt.gz | awk '$1==1 && ($2>=1001 && $2<=1003)'
```

In case you need to look for lines which simply starts from ` then do following.

```
zcat file1.txt.gz | awk '/^1/ && ($2>=1001 && $2<=1003)'
```

Comment: I am calling this in a  bash script, so would I need to put quotes in bigger than and smaller than signs?

Comment: @bapors, if you are simple calling this in script no need to do anything else, if you are taking this command's value to a variable then need to use `var=$(above command)`. Let me know if this helps.